# Open link on Button

Tags: android, cordova

i'm still new and totally noob so please carry on with me . 
how to open a link when button clicked in android?

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Edit: i'm using phonegap plugin . thanks

Comment: You should probably tell us where the link is located at? Is the link stored in a listview? Is it in a textview? where is the link that will be opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PhoneGap, un-comment either of the methods below:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //super.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        // or
        //loadUril("www.google.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: super.loadUrl("www.google.com"); really easy it works like a charm . thank you. and thank u all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Write this code inside onClick :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also add the following line to your manifest.xml because you need to have Internet permission to actually use the internet :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Read more about [Android Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html).

To read more about Uri refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) link. Also read how [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) work in Android.